# How to align to the right an actionButton inside a ConditionalPanel?

Tags: r, shiny, action-button, shinywidgets

I am creating a shiny app where depending on your `selectInput`, you will see an extra `actionButton` or not. In order to get that, this extra button has to be inside a `conditionalPanel`.

I want to have both `actionButton`s aligned, the regular one on the left and the extra, on the right. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538274/13997761) I managed to move it to the right, but they are not aligned as you can see in the attached image.

[image: image 1]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    useShinyFeedback(),
    selectInput(inputId = "type", label = "Select your data", 
                choices =  c("Data 1" = "data1",
                             "Data 2" = "data2")),
    
    actionButton(
      inputId = "button",
      label = "Submit type of data",
      icon = icon("check")
    ),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
      div(style = "position:absolute;right:1em;",
        actionButton(
          inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
          label = "More info",
          icon = icon("info-circle"))
      )
    )
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    if(input$type == "data2"){
      show_alert(
        title = "Are you sure?",
        text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
        type = "warning",
        html = TRUE
      )
      
    }else{
      show_alert(
        title = "OK",
        text = "You don't have to do anything",
        type = "success"
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$type,{
    feedbackWarning(inputId = "type",
                    show = ("data2" %in% input$type),
                    text ="This data is... Please, be careful..."
    )
  })
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    if(input$type == "data1"){
      mtcars
    }else{
      iris
    }
      
    }) %>% bindEvent(input$button)
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(mydata())
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also tried what they answered in:

1- This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402708/align-actionbutton-with-selectinput-horizontally-in-shiny), but it doesn't work for me because I am not working with columns.

```
conditionalPanel(
   condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
     actionButton(
                  inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
                  label = "More info",
                  icon = icon("info-circle"),
                  style = 'margin-top:25px'
        )
    )
```

2- These two from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749693/shiny-r-aligning-buttons):

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
      div(style="display:inline-block",
        actionButton(
          inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
          label = "More info",
          icon = icon("info-circle"),
          style="float:right")
      )
    )

 conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
      div(style = "display:inline-block; float:right",
        actionButton(
          inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
          label = "More info",
          icon = icon("info-circle"))
      )
    )
```

3- And this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28713982/13997761) (but I think it depends on another `actionButton` and it doesn't work for me).

```
conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
          div(style = "display:inline-block",
            actionButton(
              inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
              label = "More info",
              icon = icon("info-circle"))
          )
        )
```

Does anybody know how to have both `actionButton`s aligned?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by chance.

The order of the `conditionalPanel` has to be moved before the regular `actionButton` and instead of writing 1em, it would be 2.5em to have the button and the `selectInput` justified.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    useShinyFeedback(),
    selectInput(inputId = "type", label = "Select your data", 
                choices =  c("Data 1" = "data1",
                             "Data 2" = "data2")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
      div(style = "position:absolute;right:2.5em;",
          actionButton(
            inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
            label = "More info",
            icon = icon("info-circle"))
      )
    ),
    
    actionButton(
      inputId = "button",
      label = "Submit type of data",
      icon = icon("check")
    ),
    
   
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    if(input$type == "data2"){
      show_alert(
        title = "Are you sure?",
        text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
        type = "warning",
        html = TRUE
      )
      
    }else{
      show_alert(
        title = "OK",
        text = "You don't have to do anything",
        type = "success"
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$type,{
    feedbackWarning(inputId = "type",
                    show = ("data2" %in% input$type),
                    text ="This data is... Please, be careful..."
    )
  })
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    if(input$type == "data1"){
      mtcars
    }else{
      iris
    }
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$button)
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(mydata())
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a `column()` construct:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "type",
      label = "Select your data",
      choices =  c("Data 1" = "data1",
                   "Data 2" = "data2")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
        actionButton(
          inputId = "button",
          label = "Submit type of data",
          icon = icon("check"),
          width = "100%"
        )
      ),
      column(4,
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
          actionButton(
            inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
            label = "More info",
            icon = icon("info-circle"),
            width = "100%"
          )
        ),
        offset = 4
      )
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    if (input$type == "data2") {
      show_alert(
        title = "Are you sure?",
        text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
        type = "warning",
        html = TRUE
      )
    } else{
      show_alert(title = "OK",
                 text = "You don't have to do anything",
                 type = "success")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$type, {
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "type",
      show = ("data2" %in% input$type),
      text = "This data is... Please, be careful..."
    )
  })
  mydata <- reactive({
    if (input$type == "data1") {
      mtcars
    } else{
      iris
    }
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$button)
  output$table <- renderDataTable(mydata())
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

---

And another one using `splitLayout`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "type",
      label = "Select your data",
      choices =  c("Data 1" = "data1",
                   "Data 2" = "data2")
    ),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("45%", "10%", "calc(45% - 8px)"), actionButton(
      inputId = "button",
      label = "Submit type of data",
      icon = icon("check"),
      width = "100%"
    ),
    div(),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
      actionButton(
        inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
        label = "More info",
        icon = icon("info-circle"),
        width = "100%"
      )
    ))
  ),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    if (input$type == "data2") {
      show_alert(
        title = "Are you sure?",
        text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
        type = "warning",
        html = TRUE
      )
    } else{
      show_alert(title = "OK",
                 text = "You don't have to do anything",
                 type = "success")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$type, {
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "type",
      show = ("data2" %in% input$type),
      text = "This data is... Please, be careful..."
    )
  })
  mydata <- reactive({
    if (input$type == "data1") {
      mtcars
    } else{
      iris
    }
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$button)
  output$table <- renderDataTable(mydata())
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the attribute `align` in `column()` to either left or right as you wish:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "type",
      label = "Select your data",
      choices =  c("Data 1" = "data1",
                   "Data 2" = "data2")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        align = "left", 
        
        actionButton(
          inputId = "button",
          label = "Submit type of data",
          icon = icon("check"),
          width = "100%"
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 6, 
        align = "right", 
        
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.type == 'data2'",
          actionButton(
            inputId = "button_more_info_data2",
            label = "More info",
            icon = icon("info-circle"),
            width = "100%"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    if (input$type == "data2") {
      show_alert(
        title = "Are you sure?",
        text = HTML("This data is....<br>Please, be careful with..."),
        type = "warning",
        html = TRUE
      )
    } else{
      show_alert(title = "OK",
                 text = "You don't have to do anything",
                 type = "success")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$type, {
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "type",
      show = ("data2" %in% input$type),
      text = "This data is... Please, be careful..."
    )
  })
  mydata <- reactive({
    if (input$type == "data1") {
      mtcars
    } else{
      iris
    }
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$button)
  output$table <- renderDataTable(mydata())
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```